# Como diminuir o tamanho apk gerado na unity?

Tags: android, unity3d, apk, unity-5

Na `Unity` percebi que o `apk` gerado sem nenhuma configuração de script de imagem de textura, ou seja sem nada sai com um tamanho de `20 MB`, porque eles sai com esse tamanho e se tem como diminuir esse tamanho?

Comment: Nunca usei Unity, mas acredito que uma dica bem simples seria verificar se o apk está sendo gerado com o `buildType release` em vez de `debug`, pois assim ele rodaria o proguard para ofuscar e minificar o apk.

Comment: @Wakim sim compreendi, no Android Studio fica visível essa configuração, mas na unity não encontrei nada relacionado

Answer (score 1):

O tamanho do apk gerado do unity depende dos *assets* que voce importou. Importe apenas os *asset packages* que você precisará.

Desculpa, o meu Unity está em inglês, por isso aqui vem assets. Não sei como estará no seu.

Comment: Pereira mesmo a pasta fazia do assets sai com tamanho informado na pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Se vc ir em Build Settings e desmarca (Delopmente Build) vai reduzir isso e so caso der erro mostra no celular ou rodando no desktop

Mais tirando isso tamanho esta correto por padrão e 20 mb pq unity leva com ele programação para roda seus projetos não precisando de mais nenhuma dll ou tais

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).